# Highlighting a specific bar with a specific value in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am currently working on the dataset "diamond", which is included in R. Specifically, I am trying to highlight the diamond price of 605, which occurs most frequently (132 times)

My code is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds) +
geom_histogram(aes(x=price), 
             binwidth = 10, 
             breaks = seq(250, 1000, 10),
             color = "black") + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("[250,590]" = "#FF0000", "[600,610]" = "#FF9999", "[620,1000]" = "#FF0000"))
```

I seemed to get everything right, besides filling in the specific intervals.

I really, would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cut`

```
#Use cut to divide price into groups and table to count frequency of each group
temp = data.frame(table(cut(x = diamonds$price, breaks = seq(250, 1000, 10))))
ggplot(diamonds) +
    geom_histogram(
        aes(x = price),
        binwidth = 10,
        breaks = seq(250, 1000, 10),
        color = "black",
        #For the group with maximum value, assign red, otherwise assign black
        fill = replace(rep("black", NROW(temp)), which.max(temp$Freq), "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Setting that `Freq == max(Freq)` is the tricky part to accommodate what OP is after and is probably best calculated outside of `ggplot`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just would have a question, why did you need to create "temp"?

Comment: @ChristophP., `geom_histogram` creates breaks and plots counts for each break. I created `temp` by using `cut` to do the same thing outside `ggplot` so that it would be easier to identify the break with the highest count.